# jsTree 3 icon position

Tags: jquery, css, jstree

I am currently trying to upgrade jsTree to version 3.3 but I am having some issues. We are using a sprite sheet for the icons and use positioning to get the correct one.
Sadly it seems that the position has been removed in the new version of jsTree. I know that I can create css classes to handle it all, but I was hoping to keep using js like before.

This is what i was using before.

```
file: {
   icon: {
          image: '/gfx/icons/tree-structure-icons.png',
          position: '0 0'
         }
},
```

Here is a jsFiddle of what I am doing now.

http://jsfiddle.net/qeqmzsaw/

As you can see I am not able to define where on my icon sheet the icon is (as I could in older versions)

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to updated your sprite so the positions of the icons match that of the default theme.

Comment: If you want more help then you need to give us a live example or a full, working snippet.

Comment: Updated with fiddle

Comment: Seems like jsTree will (programmatically) set the inline style for the icon, so you won't be able to override this even with the css.  You may choose to tweak that part of the jsTree code.

Comment: It shouldn't be extremely difficult - http://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/qeqmzsaw/3/

Comment: Were you able to do what you wanted?